# Installed a third party python module - still won't import (windows)

Tags: python, windows, import, module, pyautogui

I'm trying to import the pyautogui module, and the error just keeps saying I don't have the module installed.

I know I have it installed, and just to check, I typed

```
pip install pyautogui
```

into my command line and it ran down the list of all the pyautogui files saying that they were already installed and in what directory.

So I figured it was an issue where I needed to set the path. I'm new to this but googling around, I figured out how to use the    sys module to add paths to Python.

So in my python text editor I typed:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Which proceeded to show me all the directories in the path. Go figure, the path with pyautogui wasn't in there.

So I added the directory with pyautogui by typing:

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\me\  etc.)
```

and it appeared to register fine. I checked    sys.path again and voila, the directory was added.

However, I then proceed to try to    import pyautogui again, and I get the same result, telling me it's not installed.

I'm a beginner and I'm not well-versed in the command line.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed and `pip` may install module in one Python but you can run code in second Python. Try `python -m pip install ...` Check also versions `pip -V` and `python -V`

Comment: saying I could not install package due to environment error [win 87]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install "pyautogui" on my Windows system.  It imported fine into a python session.

This is what I used to install pyautogui on a miniconda3 setup:

```
conda activate base
(base) c:\python\conda3>pip.exe install pyautogui
```

**How to reinstall python to a different folder**

You may need to remove all python and start over.  During installation, on the first splash screen, there is a "custom" button or something like it.  When you click on it, you can type in the folder path.  You may need to create an empty folder named "python" first.  This example will assume **python** is installed into "c:\Users\Pedro\python".

**How to install pyautogui module**

On a non-conda setup:

```
# Assuming you installed python into C:\Users\Pedro\python\
# cmd.exe window will open at the default directory. Notice the prompt.
c:\Users\Pedro>

# Change directory "cd" into the python root folder.
# Relative path is "cd python".
c:\Users\Pedro>cd python (enter key)

# Or use absolute path
c:\Users\Pedro>cd C:\Users\Pedro\python  (enter key)

# The command prompt will change to the new location.
c:\Users\Pedro\python>

# Install pyautogui from this python root location.
c:\Users\Pedro\python>pip.exe install pyautogui

# This will put pyautogui module in the right python folder.
# That is, relative to python root \python\Lib\site-packages\module-name.
```

You can check your current Windows setup for python USER PATH.  If you need to, add PATH settings manually.  For python, you need (root, Lib, site-packages, and Scripts).  If you are missing any of these, you can get an import error, module not found.

```
c:\Users\Pedro\python\
c:\Users\Pedro\python\Lib\
c:\Users\Pedro\python\Lib\site-packages\  
c:\Users\Pedro\python\Scripts\
```

**How to edit Windows Environment User PATH**

From Windows-Key, Search Box, type "environment", you should see "Edit the System Environment Variables" item.  Click on this.  You'll see "System Properties" window, on "Advanced" tab, click button "Environment Variables".

Next you will see "Environment Variables" windows.  Top part has User "Path" (click on it to highlight the line).  Then click "Edit" button.

Now you will see "Edit environment variables" window. See if you have all python paths I have posted above.  Click "New" button to add paths if needed.  You may also move them up to the top.  If you have multiple python paths, that is OK.  Just move the ones you are using now to the top.

[image: Command - Search box]

[image: Environment Variable window]

[image: Edit python Env Var USER PATH]

Comment: Woah. Thanks. Busy currently but will give this a try and get back to you!

Comment: You're the best! But I still couldn't get it to work, even when I manually entered those paths. I actually got so frustrated I deleted them all, and now my "PATH" settings are blank. Is PATH something that was installed along with Python? Do I have to go back and fix this? All the things I'm doing, I'm trying to do at work as a User. I installed Python on my work computer just fine, and I think I even have admin privileges in the command line. It's just this pesky pyautogui module. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How do I choose where python installs? My directory always says C:\User\MyName\Local\ etc... and I think python needs to be inside of my user because I'm downloading it at work and can't download it to the entire computer. I think a lot of my problems are because I'm not just working on my laptop, I'm working on a PC at work that is attached to a larger network

Comment: Ok but if it is C:\python, doesn't that mean it's at a higher level than my User? I can't download outside of my own User. But I can create a Python folder inside my User path. Should I do this?

Comment: I love you. Thanks for the time you took to answer my dumbass questions. So basically when I cd into that folder, anything I install in the cmd.exe after that will be automatically placed in that folder?

Comment: Thanks I will screenshot. Accepting your comment!

Comment: Hi Pedro,  Thanks for the points.  I have modified my answer above to include most of my previous comments.  Hope you will be able to get it working. :-)